# Javascript Regex: null is lower case letter?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone explain why `/[a-z]/.test(null)` returns `true` while `/[A-Z]/.test(null)` returns `false`? Is `null` (or `undefined` or `false`) considered a lower case letter in Javascript? Thanks.

Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Just a guess, thus not posted as answer: Maybe it tests against the value's string representation, so "null" of "false" or "undefined" would contain lowercase letters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you test anything but a String, it is turned into a String. `null` is turned into a string `'null'`. Try it: `console.log(new String(null));`

Likewise for `undefined`.

Comment: but `/[a-z]/.test(NaN)` is also `true`

Comment: Ohhh JavaScript.  Gotta love it.

Comment: @gefei Yes, `a` is a lowercase match.

Comment: I would like to add that the RegExp `/x/` matches if the tested string *contains* `x`. "NaN" conmtains a lower-case 'a', which is why it matches.

Comment: Well, the output of `console.log(new String(null))` might look surprising. What Javascript actually does here is `String(null)`, not `new String`.

Answer (score 4):

Per ECMAScript 5's [section 15.10.6.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3), `test` is largely a wrapper for `exec`, which is in [section 15.10.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2):

> #### RegExp.prototype.exec(string)
>
> 1. Let R be this RegExp object.
> 2. Let S be the value of ToString(string).
>
> ...

Thus, we see that the argument to `test` (when passed through to `exec`) is coerced via the `ToString` operation. When we look at ToString in [section 9.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) we see the conversion table:

> The abstract operation ToString converts its argument to a value of type String according to Table 13:
>
> #### Table 13 — ToString Conversions
>
> ```
> Argument Type   Result
> Undefined     | "undefined"
> Null          | "null"
> ...
> ```

Null values stringify to the string `"null"` , which has lowercase characters that match `/[a-z]/`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `RegExp.test` acts on a `String`, `null` will be casted to type `String`, so it becomes

```
/[a-z]/.test("null");
```

Comment: Explain the downvote..getting random downvotes a lot today.